# jquery animate not working in IE9?

Tags: jquery-animate, internet-explorer-9, toggle, compatibility

I hope you can help.

I can get this working perfectly in other browsers but not in IE9 - I've found the jsfiddle which utilises animate and works perfectly animating in IE9 so it suggests the problem is not with 'animate' as such.

http://jsfiddle.net/Rykus0/Q9vng/

My link below followed by the offending code:

http://the3rdobject.com/test/index.html

```
<script>
    $(function(){
        $(".collectionbutton").click(function(){
            if($(".collectionbutton a").hasClass('openpanel')){
                $(".text").animate({top:'-' + $(".text-content-container").css('height') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").toggle();

            } else {
                $(".text").animate({top:$(".text-content-container").css('') + 'px'}, 500);
                $(".collectionbutton a").addClass('openpanel');
            }   
        });
    });
    </script>
```

It switches the name on the button to show and hide accordingly but won't animate. I've noticed some people saying on other similar threads that its due to opacity but my opacity is set within the css which should be fine. I'd really appreciate some help with this as my jquery is not strong and I'm nearly bald!

G

Comment: css animations are not supported in IE9.
Have you tested on IE11?
You did not mention which jquery and jquery.ui version you are using. You need to be using the latest versions that include the ms prefixed css animation rules.

Comment: Hi Rob, Yes I've tested in IE11 and it works perfectly. Am using jquery 1.11.2, modernizr-2.8.3-respond-1.4.2.min.js,  though I'm a newb so not sure what you are referring to with version of jquery.ui? Could the problem be that I'm using 'jquery.animate-enhanced.min.js' - does this convert to css? As the jsfiddle link I posted would suggest, the problem is not with the .animate function, but something else... I've got something working using SlideUp, SlideDown, however, my clickbutton disappears on click. Any ideas? I'm a bit stumped with my limited Jquery knowledge!

Comment: Hi Rob, In addition, can you tell me what part of my code is using a css animation? I was under the impression that .animate was jquery?